# Streaming over rtsp on android

Tags: android, video-streaming, rtsp

I am trying to play a rtsp video using a video view, it works well, play the video but there are problems which i am facing:

1. It is not buffering the video, e.g. i watched the video for 2 mins and now i want to play it from one minute back again. I used the slider for going back to 1 min but when i do this it re buffers the video again.
2. When the video playback is completed it throws an **error-48** every time in stead of calling `onCompletion`.

Here is my code for playing the video:

```
String videoPath = "rtsp url";
mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoPath));
mVideoView.requestFocus();
mVideoView.start();
```

Please suggest, what should i do to avoid/resolve these problems.

Comment: have you set onCompletionListener. setOnCompletionListener(OnCompletionListener).

Comment: Yes, I have done that. I have setup both errorListener and onCompletion methods.

Answer (score 1):

1. It is streaming method of video delivery. Video players shouldn't buffering video. They can't do "seek" in buffered data, for example.
2. May be, it is server problem.